# XSLT: Remove certain text within XML tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml document as follows,

```
<footnote>
   <p type="Footnote Text">
      <link ref="http://www.apple.com/accessibility/iphone/hearing.html">
         <c type="Hyperlink">http:.apple.com/accessibility/iphone/hearing.html
         </c>
       </link>
     </s>
    </p>
</footnote>
```

what I need to do is from xslt I need to remove sub-strings of the url within  tag.

Example :

original xml document like this,

```
<c type="Hyperlink">http:www.apple.com/accessibility/iphone/hearing.html
 </c>
```

and I need to convert as follows :

```
<c type="Hyperlink">www.apple.com </c>
```

I searched for XSLT inbuild functions for remove certain substrings in a string but I could not find such a function.

can u give any suggestion how I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `c` element could be converted in this way:

```
<xsl:template match="c">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:variable name="sa" select="substring-after(.,':')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="sb" select="substring-before($sa,'/')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$sb"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Please note that your example is not a valid XML file, there are problems with closing tags.